# Polar coordinates for improper integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, polar-coordinates

One way to prove that the area under the graph of the Gaussian function $e^{-x^2}$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$ is to compute the quantity $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}$ using a change to polar coordinates. However, this proof uses the fact that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \thinspace dy \thinspace dx 
= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty f(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)r \thinspace dr \thinspace d\theta.$$

The only calculus text I own is Stewart's Calculus, which does not go into improper integrals in polar coordinates. Where can I find a proper statement and proof of this fact?

Comment: Using polar cordinates $x=rcos{\theta}$ and $y=rsin{\theta}$, using jacobian to change $dxdy = rdrd{\theta}$. Clearly, the $r$ ranges from $0 to \infty$ and ${\theta}$ varies from $0 to 2\pi$ covering whole circle.

Comment: Find the integral on the area between a circle and a box tangent to it, then take the limit as both shapes get larger. The integral on that small corner should go to $0$